# General distribution of Coumpound poisson process as a limit of poisson random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S_t$ be a compound Poisson process, i.e.

$$S_t= \sum_{i=0}^{N(t)} X_i,$$
where $N(t)$ is a Poisson process and $X_i$ are iid and independent from $N_t$.

I know that in general the distribution of $S_t$ is complicated and has the form

$$P(S_t\leq x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty F_X^{*k}(x)\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}$$

for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\lambda$ is the intensity of $N_t$ and $F_X^{*k}(x)$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $X_i$. I'm trying to prove that the limit of a linear combinations of independent Poisson random variables with some parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ...$ for some constant values $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...$ has the same distribution.

$$
P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iY_i \leq x) = P(S_t \leq x)
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for a fixed $t\geq 0$, where $Y_i \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_i)$.

How could I go about proving this result. My professor told me it's simple to derive, but I must admit that I'm stuggling a bit, and have not found literature that proves the result.

Comment: If no one is willing to help, could I get some feedback of what is wrong with my question so I can rephrase it or add missing information?

Comment: What do you mean by limit of independent Poisson random variables?

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question so it says "sum" (I don't know why I wrote "limit"; temporary lapse of judgment). To be honest, this was in the context of my bachelor's thesis, where my professor gave me some direction on where to take the subject mattes; this is the point at which I got stuck. I believe I can prove it using characteristic functions, but don't know how to construct te full proof.

Comment: I'm assuming that there must be some condition on the $X_i$ as well as the $\lambda_i$? Otherwise we could just take $X_i= 0$ and this is false. Could you edit the question to reflect precisely what your professor said?

Comment: I believe I specified what I intend to prove now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I've posted an answer for the case that $X$ is discrete. I believe the general case is significantly harder (if it is even true).

Answer (score 0):

We first compute the characteristic function $\mathbb{E}[e^{iuS_t}]$ of $S_t$ in terms of the characteristic function $\Phi$ of $X$ as follows $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[e^{iuS_t}] &= \sum_{j\ge 0} \mathbb{E}[e^{iuS_t}|S_t=j] \mathbb{P}(S_t=j)\\
&= \sum_{j\ge 0} \mathbb{E}[e^{iu(X_1+\ldots+X_j)}] \mathbb{P}(S_t=j)\\
&= \sum_{j\ge 0} \Phi(u)^j \frac{(\lambda t)^j)}{j!} e^{-\lambda t}\\
&= \exp(\Phi(u)\lambda t-\lambda t)\\
&= \exp((\Phi(u)-1)\lambda t).
\end{align*}$$
By considering the case $X_i = \alpha_j$ and $S_t \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda_j)$ in the above we also get the characteristic function of $\alpha_j Y_j$ for a Poisson random variable $Y_j$ of parameter $\lambda_j$ as $$\mathbb{E}[e^{iu\alpha_j Y_j}] = \exp(\lambda_j (e^{iu\alpha_j}-1)).$$
Therefore to get the desired convergence it suffices to find $\alpha_j,\lambda_j$ such that $$\sum_{j\ge 0} \lambda_j(e^{iu\alpha_j}-1) = (\Phi(u)-1)\lambda t \tag{$\ast$}$$
for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$.

For general $X$ I am not sure whether this is possible, but in the case $X$ is discrete, we can take $\{\beta_j\}_{j\ge 0}$ to be the range of $X$ so that $$\Phi(u) = \sum_{j\ge 0} e^{iu \beta_j} \mathbb{P}(X=\beta_j) $$
and $(\ast)$ becomes $$\sum_{j\ge 0} \lambda_j(e^{iu\alpha_j}-1) = \lambda t\sum_{j\ge 0} e^{iu \beta_j} \mathbb{P}(X=\beta_j) - \lambda t$$
so a natural choice is to take $\alpha_j = \beta_j$ and $\lambda_j = \lambda t {\mathbb{P}(X=\beta_j)}$, which indeed works.